# Merging 2 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want to merge 2 classes or add all methods from 1 class to another. In the future It will be the more classes than just a (ContainerClient) class.

`Client` and `ContainerClient`

I tried this but I think It can be done even easier.

```
for (var a of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ContainerClient.prototype)) {
  Client.prototype[a] = ContainerClient.prototype[a];
}
```

Principle: `ContainerClient` depends on `Client`

### Data.js

```js
class Data {
  constructor () {

  }
}
```

### Client.js

```js
class Client extends Data {
  me () {
    return {
      id: '1',
    };
  }
}
```

### Container.js

```js
class Container extends Data {
  containers () {
    return [
      {
        clientId: '1',
        id: '2',
      },
      {
        clientId: '2',
        id: '3',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

### ContainerClient.js

```js
class ContainerClient extends Data {
  containers () {
    return {
      clientId: '1',
      id: '2',
    };
  }
}
```

## --> Client.js before `export` <--

```js
// --> HERE <--
for (var a of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ContainerClient.prototype)) {
  Client.prototype[a] = ContainerClient.prototype[a];
}

// -> [ 'constructor', 'me', 'containers' ]​​​​​ 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Client.prototype));
```

### index.js

```js
const client = new Client();
const container = new Container();

// -> { clientId: '1', id: '2' }​​​​​ 
console.log(client.containers());
```

Comment: If `Client` and `ContainerClient` both extend `Data`, why not just make `Client` extend `ContainerClient`? The naming sounds a bit counterintuitive though, but your description is basically this.

Comment: Because in the future It will be the more classes than just a (ContainerClient) class.

Comment: That's not a reason not to follow @MátéSafranka advice. And if your code creates a reason for this, change the code that led to this situation

Comment: Fair enough. AFAIK your method is about as simple as it gets, until JS starts supporting mixins natively. If you use this sort of composition a lot, you can just write a little helper function for it.

Comment: OK, I just woke up, so I may not be getting this correctly, but to me it sounds you are trying to use a golden hammer here. Are you sure you don't want to use [*composition* over inheritance](https://medium.com/humans-create-software/composition-over-inheritance-cb6f88070205)? Instead of "merging" classes, separating the concepts - a class is something the object *is* functionality can be added to object that needs it. After think about this conceptually - you have a `Human` and a `Dog` and you want to share make the two share features - do you make a HumanDog abomination?

Comment: @vlaz (opinion/philosophy incoming) Composition over inheritance is more for strictly typed languages such as Java. One of the big features of JS is the flexibility it gives you in assembling your prototypes however you want, similarly to how traits work in PHP, for example. At the end of the day it's largely a matter of personal taste and whatever's fitting for the use case, but I firmly believe we shouldn't dismiss this approach just because it's not en vogue in other programming circuits.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I agree with you, however it seems to me that OP is getting trapped in inheritance. I can't think of a single reason you'd have two classes that both extend the same parent class and you'd want to "merge" them. Not in Java, not in JavaScript, not in anything. As I said, even conceptually it seems wrong. Again, do you make `HumanDog` because a `Human` can walk and `Dog` can eat, for example?

Comment: The code in the question isn't specific enough to get a specific answer, but from what it looks like this is a perfect case for composition over inheritance. `Client extends Data` just doesn't make sense. Clients use data, not inherit from it.

Comment: @vlaz I do agree with you as well that combining classes that inherit from the same parent doesn't sound like a good idea; like I said in my first comment, that's basically just inheritance. Your `HumanDog` example feels a bit like *reductio ad absurdum* to me, but that's just rhetorics. In practice, traits/mixins should come from a separate inheritance chain from what you're mixing them into. Bottom line, OP might want to rethink their inheritance structure, but don't need to discount mixins entirely IMHO.

Comment: @estus thank you. That's sort of what I meant by misusing inheritance. Need coffee to start being more coherent, I guess.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I'd call it less reductio ad absurdum and more "Can't think of a proper example right now, so I made up one to be illustrative"

Comment: "*but I think It can be done even easier*" - why do you think so? And does your current attempt work for you?

Comment: @MátéSafranka Yes, mixins might be the answer, but mixins should not use `class` syntax

Comment: @MátéSafranka Mixins. That is what I was looking for. 

Comment: @vlaz MPJ (the author in your article) got composition completely, entirely wrong, and actual composition never once made an appearance in his article/video. What he actually described, without him realizing it, is multiple inheritance. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the short answer: What you're doing is (almost) the best you can do. For a tiny improvement, you could replace the for loop with Object.assign and that would shorten it up by a line, but it'll still do the same thing.

Now the long answer.

I'll open by saying that I agree with a lot of the comments that this design smells (as in code smell). Most likely there should be no inheritance, and each type should be *using* instances of the others. Clients should *use* data objects. Containers should be an array of client objects. And so forth.

With that disclaimer, here's the more direct answer to your question.

The name of what you're looking for is multiple inheritance / mixins. Python, just for a quick example, natively supports multiple inheritance, so in Python you'd be able to write:

```
class Client(Data, ContainerClient):
    ...
```

But JavaScript's prototype chain supports only single inheritance, so you'll have to settle for some kind of workaround. One such workaround [creates subclasses on the fly with a variable base](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#sec_simple-mixins). Something like:

```
const ClientMixin = Sup => class extends Sup {
    // ...
};
const ContainerMixin = Sup => class extends Sup {
    // ...
};
```

Then you can define your concrete classes like this:

```
class Container extends ContainerMixin(Data) {
    // ...
}

class ContainerClient extends ClientMixin(ContainerMixin(Data)) {
    // ...
}
```

Whether this seems easier than what you were already doing is up to you. Because the other workaround, of course, is to simply copy properties from one class to another like you were doing.